# No swap installed. Why is swap value still 60?

Tags: partitioning, swap

I purposely installed 14.04.01 LTS with no swap partition because I do not require it for what I do. Just curious why  `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` still produces a value of 60.

I'm considering modifying my `/etc/sysctl.conf` to have `vm.swappiness=0`. Regardless of that, I just wonder why it set a default swap value on a machine with no swap installed at all.

Why is this? Is the kernel still going to try and swap since it had a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` is used to decide [what and how much to swap](https://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/tales-from-responsivenessland-why-linux-feels-slow-and-how-to-fix-that), *when you have swap space available*.

It obviously does nothing if you have no swap space configured; but in Linux you can add swap space in any moment via, for example, [swap files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/swap#Swap_file) --- and in that case the system will behave following the parameters it has set.